# Antlr4 Grammar fails to parse

Tags: antlr4

I am new to ANTLR, and here is a grammar that I am working on and its failing for a given input string -  A.B() && ((C.D() || E.F())).

I have tried a number of combinations but its failing on the same place.

```
grammar Expressions;

expression                                                 
            : logicBlock (logicalConnector logicBlock)*
            | NOT? '('? logicBlock ')'? (logicalConnector  NOT? '('? logicBlock ')'?)*            
            ;

logicBlock
            : logicUnit comparator THINGS                                                       
            | logicUnit comparator logicUnit                                                    
            | logicUnit                                                                  
            ;

logicUnit
            : NOT? '(' method ')'                                                            
            | NOT? method                                                                       
            ;


method
            : object '.' function ('.' function)*                                               
           ;

object
            : THINGS                                                                            
            |'(' THINGS ')'                                                                     
            ;

function
            : THINGS '(' arguments? ')'                                                         
            ;

arguments
            : (object | function | method | logicUnit | logicBlock)
            (
                ','
                (object | function | method | logicUnit | logicBlock)

            )*                                                                                  
            ;

logicalConnector
            : AND | OR | PLUS | MINUS
            ;

comparator
            : GT | LT | GTE | LTE | EQUALS | NOTEQUALS
            ;


AND         : '&&'  ;
OR          : '||'  ;
EQUALS      : '=='  ;
ASSIGN      : '='   ;
GT          : '>'   ;
LT          : '<'   ;
GTE         : '>='  ;
LTE         : '<='  ;
NOTEQUALS   : '!='  ;
NOT         : '!'   ;
PLUS        : '+'   ;
MINUS       : '-'   ;
IF          : 'if'  ;

THINGS
            : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
            | '"' .*? '"'
            | [0-9]+
            | ([0-9]+)? '.' ([0-9])+
            ;

WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
            ;
```

The error that I getting for this input -  A.B() && ((C.D() || E.F())) is below. any help and/or suggestion to improve would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule looks odd to me:

```
expression                                                 
 : logicBlock (logicalConnector logicBlock)*
 | NOT? '('? logicBlock ')'? (logicalConnector  NOT? '('? logicBlock ')'?)* 
   //    ^               ^                            ^               ^
   //    |               |                            |               |
 ;
```

All the optional parenthesis can't be right: this means the the first can be present, and the other 3 would be omitted (and any other combination), leaving your expression with unbalanced parenthesis.

The get your grammar working in the input `A.B() && ((C.D() || E.F()))` , you'll want to do something like this:

```
expression
 : logicBlock (logicalConnector logicBlock)*
 | NOT? logicBlock (logicalConnector  NOT? logicBlock)*
 ;

logicBlock
 : '(' expression ')'
 | logicUnit comparator THINGS
 | logicUnit comparator logicUnit
 | logicUnit
 ;

logicUnit
 : '(' expression ')'
 | NOT? '(' method ')'
 | NOT? method
 ;
```

But ANTLR4 supports left recursive rules, allowing you to define the expression rule like this:

```
expression
 : '(' expression ')'
 | NOT expression
 | expression comparator expression
 | expression logicalConnector expression
 | method
 | object
 | THINGS
 ;

method
 : object '.' function ( '.' function )*
 ;

object
 : THINGS
 |'(' THINGS ')'
 ;

function
 : THINGS '(' arguments? ')'
 ;

arguments
 : expression ( ',' expression )*
 ;

logicalConnector
 : AND | OR | PLUS | MINUS
 ;

comparator
 : GT | LT | GTE | LTE | EQUALS | NOTEQUALS
 ;
```

making it much more readable. Sure, it doesn't produce the exact parse tree your original grammar was producing, but you might be flexible in that regard. This proposed grammar also matches more than yours: like `NOT A`, which your grammar does not allow, where my proposed grammar does accept it.

Comment: Thanks Bart K. I tried couple of combinations and it works.

Comment: My original intention was to sperate logicalConnector (AND OR PLUS MINUS). and that's why i went to the path of introducing logicBlock and logicUnit. However, with the new grammar, i need to carry out multiple pass untill the input == ouput for "expression" rule. Wondering if there's is any codesnippet that does the same.